# How can I convert this from webkit to moz?

Tags: css, webkit

How can I convert this from webkit to moz?

```
background-color: #fff; 
background-image: 
-webkit-linear-gradient(0deg, transparent 79px, #ABCED4 79px, #ABCED4 81px, transparent 81px), 
-webkit-linear-gradient(#EEE .05em, transparent .05em);
```

Comment: um... replace `webkit` by `moz`?

Comment: @alex well, I don't mean to be a smartass, and there may be something deeper going on here... But I really wouldn't know what :)

Comment: IIRC There was a difference between the webkit version and the moz version.

Comment: http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/

Comment: @Truth Yeah, there are differences :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To support most browsers...

```
background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(171,206,212,1) 79px, rgba(0,0,0,0) 81px); /* FF3.6+ */
background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(79px,rgba(171,206,212,1)), color-stop(81px,rgba(0,0,0,0))); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(171,206,212,1) 79px,rgba(0,0,0,0) 81px); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
background: -o-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(171,206,212,1) 79px,rgba(0,0,0,0) 81px); /* Opera 11.10+ */
background: -ms-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(171,206,212,1) 79px,rgba(0,0,0,0) 81px); /* IE10+ */
background: linear-gradient(top,  rgba(171,206,212,1) 79px,rgba(0,0,0,0) 81px); /* W3C */
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#abced4', endColorstr='#00000000',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-9 */
```

Obviously, the first line is the one with the `moz` vendor prefix.

You could also just [wait until Firefox supports the `webkit` vendor prefix](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/the-vendor-prefix-predicament-alas-eric-meyer-interviews-tantek-celik/) :P.

Comment: It would be a very black day if that ever happens.

Comment: @Truth I blame the dodgy developers who only use the `webkit` vendor prefix.

Comment: Second that, but there are others to blame (for example, the CSSWG struggling with the definitions for ages, not completing the specs fast enough), but yes, most of the blame is on these.